# Is there a site for mobile app usage questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Do we have a Stack Exchange site available yet for using mobile apps?

Looked through the list, but didn't notice one, though of course it could have a name that didn't trigger my search function.

Comment: Are you asking about app *development*  or *usage*?

Comment: @RobertCartaino, usage. Edited.

Comment: I use Stack Exchange, it has all of Stack apps in one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your device, one of these sites might be for you. However some questions are off-topic on all three sites (buying recommendations). So be sure to read the help center and tour before asking.

- [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is for users of the Android operating system.
  >
  > If your question generally covers...
  >
  > - Using your Android device
  > - **Using a particular app on your Android device**
  > - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device
  >
  > then this is the right place to ask. Basically, what problem (with your Android device) are you trying to solve?
- [Ask Different (Apple)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > Ask Different is for users of Apple products. If you have a question about a practical problem you are trying to solve as a user of...
  >
  > - Apple hardware
  > - Apple software
  > - Apple services including iTunes Connect (selling music, books, apps)
  > - **third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products.**
  >
  > ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!
  >
  > The following topics are expressly ***off-topic*** here:
  >
  > - Shopping or buying recommendations. Questions that are mainly about price/time/supply constraints are considered "shopping" questions.
  > - Customer Support and questions about the particulars of specific games, such as game account or in-app purchase issues, should be directed to support staff.
- [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > Windows Phone Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Windows Phone operating system, and the problems they face
  >
  > If your question generally covers...
  >
  > - Using your Windows Phone device
  > - Using a particular app on your device
  > - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your device
  >
  > then this is the right place to ask. Basically, what problem (with your phone) are you trying to solve?

Comment: Also [windows phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [tag:status-completed]